# Elasticsearch when to reindex?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

i suppose one of the biggest costs in elastic search is reindexing. when do we reindex ?

what if we got adaptive models and we re index frequently would elastic search make sense in that scenerio.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't have to reindex too often. It's mostly for when you make a "schema" change to your source database and you need the new index to reflect that. If your models change often, Elasticsearch will simply store the new data since it auto maps the new fields.

If the change on our source database is big enough, then you could consider reindexing but then you may have to take care to make sure your searches still work. I think this would have to be a judgement call on your part. If you simply added a new field to your source database, any new searches could take that into account and you wouldn't have to reindex. IF you are doing a major schema change at your source database and the fields have new or different data types, then you could consider a reindex.

The ES site has some tips on reindexing http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html

Comment: I got an adaptive schema so I am considering reindex too often. Such as If ı got 10.000 indexes and I changed the schema of one of them. Will that create an expensive reindex job ?

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin I don't know for sure but I don't think you should have to re index to be honest. Your new data will just use the new fields, correct?

Comment: I need to test it before I mark it answer. I need to learn with indexes gets updated on the reindex.Only the modified ones?